# Translate C# class to python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got C# class defined as follows. I got one constructor and inner class with properties. How can i translate it to python?

```
class Person
{
    Property string Name {get;set;}
    Proeprty InnerClass MyInnerClass {get;set;}

    //constructor
    Person(string name, InnerClass myinnerClass)
    {
        Name = name;
        MyInnerClass = myinnerClass;
        MyInnerClass .car = "Mercedes";
    }
    
    class InnerClass
    {
        Property string Car {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Main thing to consider is that python doesn't normally use getters and setters. You can either just access the properties directly for Name and MyInnerClass, or use the @property decorator to access those properties via functions.

Answer (score 2):

There are some pretty stark differences between Python and C#, but I'll provide an approximation that's about as close as you're going to get. In Python, there is no real concept of 'private' or 'public' variables. everything is just public by default.

There are ways of denoting in python whether a property should be internal or external, but since all of the variables in your example were public anyway, I won't worry about that.

Anyway, here goes nothing:

```py
class Person: 

    class InnerClass:
        def __init__(self, car=None):
            self.car = car

    def __init__(self, name:str, myinnerClass: InnerClass):
        self.Name = name
        self.MyInnerClass = myinnerClass
        self.MyInnerClass.car = "Mercedes"
```

Comment: Let's imagine Property string Car {get;set;} in InnerClass is now: Property string Car<Car>{get;set;} . Would be any diffrence to your code?

Comment: Hi Henry... that line doesn't make sense, even in C#.  you should go read up on using generics in C# for those angle bracket <types>.

Comment: I ment Property List<Car> Car {get;set;}

Comment: it still doesn't make sense. nowhere do you have defined a `class Car`

Answer (score 0):

Not a C# programmer, but if a property is defined with default `get; set;`, I don't see a need to make it access-controlled. If you need pseudo-private variables or mutators with side-effects, look into the Python `property` decorator.

```py
class Person:
    # use __slots__ if your class's attributes can be determined at
    # "compile"-time
    __slots__ = ["name", "inner_obj"] 

    def __init__(name: str, inner_obj: 'Person.InnerClass') -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.inner_obj = inner_obj
        self.inner_obj.car = "Mercedes"

    class InnerClass:
         __slots__ = ["car"]
```